# Disable zoom when textfields in UIWebView active

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am developing an iPhone App based on a UIWebView (hate it or love it). This page has a fixed width and pretty much static proportions. I have a few input textfields on this page, but whenever a user engages focus on one of these, the iPhone will zoom a bit in. Also, I can pinch-zoom on the web view.

How can I avoid that? I have Scaling: Scales Page To Fit and View Mode: Scale To Fill.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try disabling it in a meta tag, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me

webViewHome.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

And Change wkwebview property set "Aspect Fit " from "Scales to fill" in storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: yes because I faced this issue and resolve so that it will help to other developers in future.

Comment: I am happy to help developers like me. Thank you :)